# "App\Model\Table\LikesTable" is aborting the transaction before the save process is done cakephp 3

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

In my website I needed a notifications which would be call me if user put like smile or something else. I did it using aftersave() method, which will work after save like or smile. When I pushed on server I got error ""App\Model\Table\LikesTable" is aborting the transaction before the save process is done.". But locally all work. I search some infromation in google. I think it's problems with mysql but I can't resolve this problem. Can you help me with it?

//Server//
Server version: 5.6.33-79.0 Percona Server (GPL), Release 79.0, Revision 2084bdb;
PHP 5.6.25 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2016 11:03:33);
 //locally mysql version: 5.6.33
php-version 5.6.23

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error message**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! Also show/describe the proper context, ie show/highlight the code that actually triggers the error, elaborate on your server environment (OS, DBMS, etc.)!, and last but not least, please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version - thanks! Often problems even solve themselves when collecting such information.

Comment: I resolved problem. It's my mistake. Table in server and table locally in mysql were different. And when after save worked it didn't see some columns which was needed. Audit of tables and migrations is very important!!)